# Oracle Index Organized Table (IOT) order by primary key suffix better than by primary key prefix

Tags: oracle11g, database-performance, query-performance

I use an Index Organized Table (IOT) for a table having 550 M rows. The primary key is composed by two columns (id1 and id2) which are also foreign key towards 2 other tables (id1 FK towards table1, id2 FK towards table2).

When using an IOT, according to Oracle doc (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables012.htm#i1007389), sorting by prefix of the primary key should be faster than sorting by suffix of the primary key. Indeed, rows are sorted according to the primary key and the order of the columns composing it.

However here are the explain plans I get when joining the IOT with the two other tables and I try to order either by id1 or id2. I would have expected to get a better cost by sorting by id1. But it is not the case.

The value used for id1 corresponds to 58000 rows among 489000 rows in total in table1. The value used for id2 corresponds to 760 rows among 248900 rows in total in table2.

The SQL query :

```
SELECT a.id1, a.id2, a.some_column
FROM iot_table a
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t1.id = a.id1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = a.id2
WHERE t1.col_x = x AND t2.col_y = y
ORDER BY {a.id1|a.id2};
```

Explain plan order by id1 :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                     
| Id  | Operation                      | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                       |       |       | 11243 (100)|          |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                  |                       |  1311K|    42M| 11243   (1)| 00:01:44 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN         |                       |    46M|   842M| 11173   (1)| 00:01:43 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | TABLE1                | 58152 |   511K|  4745   (1)| 00:00:44 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|   4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN            | TABLE1_ID1_IDX        |   488K|       |    15   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|   5 |    BUFFER SORT                 |                       |   799 |  7990 |  6429   (1)| 00:01:00 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE2                |   799 |  7990 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|*  7 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | TABLE2_COL_Y_IDX      |   799 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|*  8 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | IOT_TABLE_PK          |     1 |    15 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

Explain plan order by id2 :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                     
| Id  | Operation                      | Name                  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT               |                       |       |       |  5159 (100)|          |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                  |                       |  1311K|    42M|  5159   (2)| 00:00:48 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN         |                       |    46M|   842M|  5089   (1)| 00:00:47 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | TABLE2                |   799 |  7990 |  2512   (1)| 00:00:24 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|   4 |     INDEX FULL SCAN            | TABLE2_ID2_IDX        |   248K|       |    28   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|   5 |    BUFFER SORT                 |                       | 58152 |   511K|  2577   (2)| 00:00:24 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|   6 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| TABLE1                | 58152 |   511K|     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|*  7 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN          | TABLE1_COL_X_IDX      | 58152 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
|*  8 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN            | IOT_TABLE_PK          |     1 |    15 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                     
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am wondering why the cost is worst for sorting by id1 whereas the rows should be primarily sorted according to this column and Oracle would just have to browse the IOT B*-Tree as it is.

Thank you for your help

I use Oracle 11.2 g and the stats are up to date.

Comment: If I remove one of the join, the behavior becomes normal : sorting by first part of the primary key is much more effecient. I still don't understand what's happen.

Comment: If I just remove the order by clause, rows are sorted by id2. It is coherent with the fact that sorting by id2 in this query is better. But why rows are "naturally" sorted by id2 with this query whereas rows are sorted by id1 in the IOT itself and in all other queries involving just 1 join or no join at all ?